# using a simple fragment in android for an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

### Using Fragments in android

I am trying to learn fragments

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment,
                                     container, false);

        Button nextButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_first);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

}
```

**In the line** ::

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment,container, false);
```

- why are we giving `false`
- what is this about `container`

### Can someone explain in laymen terms, in simplest terms

Please go easy on answers ... i am a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it all in the documentation: [Android Developer Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29)

> public View inflate (XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)

And the parameters you're asking about are:

> **root**  Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)
>
> **attachToRoot**  Whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter? If false, root is only used to create the correct subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML.

Also, mind the return value as it depends on those parameters:

> **Returns**
> The root View of the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied and attachToRoot is true, this is root; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file.